# Can't set Orchard field values unless item already created

Tags: orchardcms

I seem to be having a problem with assigning values to fields of a content item with a custom content part and the values not persisting.

I have to create the content item (`OrchardServices.ContentManager.Create`) first before calling the following code which modifies a field value:

```
var fields = contentItem.As<MyPart>().Fields;

var imageField = fields.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name.Equals("Image"));

if (imageField != null)
{
    ((MediaLibraryPickerField)imageField).Ids = new int[] { imageId };
}
```

The above code works perfectly when against an item that already exists, but the `imageId` value is lost if this is done before creating it.

Please note, this is not exclusive to `MediaLibraryPickerField`s.

I noticed that other people have reported this aswell:

https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18412

Is it simply the case that an item must be created prior to amending it's value field?

This would be a shame, as I'm assigning this fields as part of a large import process and would inhibit performance to create it and then modify the item only to update it again.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments on this issue explain, you do need to call `Create`. I'm not sure I understand why you think that is an issue however.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. To me it's a shame that only certain parts of the object can be created as part of the `Create` process (i.e. not all data assigned will be persisted). I'm having to create many hundreds of items, then go back over them all and update them again. It seems inefficient, if only for the way it demands I structure my code.

Comment: What do you mean not all data assigned will be persisted? It will if you set it after the call to create. Why would you have to go back to the items and update them twice?

Comment: Thanks for confirming this is how it works. In my case I need to import a lot of data and perform several kinds of validation and geolocation lookups and such before creating the item. So I'm currently keeping all field values in variables until all validation is done. Is there a good way to "undo" the creation of an item? (Or permanently delete it so there is no trace of it left in the database?)